# Java Threads 64bit formula?

Tags: java

Couple of questions:

Is there a non-JConsole command-line interface to get the amount of threads running under a Java process in Linux?

Also, is there a formula for calculating max number of threads based on stack size, box memory, and heap size for a 64 bit machine?

Comment: Just because you can have N thread on a machine before it fails, doesn't mean this is a good idea.  Note: You can have only one thread per logical process running at any moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Java threads are implemented on OS level, you could see the number threads using for instance `htop`.

Generally, on a linux system a thread poses extremely little overhead by itself. So even if you figured out some formula to compute the maximum number of threads, it would be an extremely high number.